# xib files in Xcode resetting UIView to a (0,0,0,0) frame

Tags: ios, xcode, uiview, xamarin, xcode6

I am experiencing a strange issue with Xcode. Drag a `UIView` onto the xib and set the frame as desired. I do some other stuff and/or leave the xib and come back and then suddenly the `UIView` I placed on the xib has a frame of (0,0,0,0). Just wondering if anyone else has experienced this and if not, is there somewhere I can submit an Xcode bug?

A few notes:

1. I am using Xamarin Studio to open the xibs in Xcode.
2. There seems to be a theme where this is happening only with UI components that inherit *directly* from `UIView`. (`UIImageView`, `UIView`, `UITextView`)
3. This only happens if the component is empty i.e. it stops happening when I add an image to `UIImageView`.

Comment: Just FYI to anyone who lands here, adding Layout Constraints fixed the issue for me. I'm not sure if this is Apple's way of forcing you to use constraints or if it's a bug, but that's the fix I found.